# What kind of Variadic function to use?

Tags: d, variadic-functions

I want to write a variadic function that should have 1 parameter that is not optional of type string and a second string that is optional. I have read the language spec about variadic functions but considering D's many options I would like to know which is the appropriate solution for my problem.

Also how should I use cast and pointer for copying the string pointed by the `void* _argptr` (the fact that strings are immutable in D confuses me I guess).

**Edit:** What I want is something like:

```
string foo (string nonopt, ...) { /*code*/ }

//...
string a = "x@a.t", b = "a.t";
auto s = foo(a);
auto s2 = foo(a, b);
```

Comment: Please improve your question title and .. write a question. This isn't a "gimme teh codez" website.

Comment: Was there _really_ a good reason for downvoting? Whoever did it - this is the main reason why people are afraid of asking questions here... I do not care about other groups, but in D I will try to answer **any** question, no matter how good/bad quality it is.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I don't know what is wrong with the title, except for the fact that it is maybe ambiguous because I was on the going on the wrong track with my code. I wrote 2 questions in fact witch were clear enough given that everyone gave basically the same answer and clarified this stuff for me. I did not asked for the codes. This was stuff I did for fun and learning programming [in D] and I could easily just post my entire code here if I wanted someone to fix it for me or to 'gimme teh codez'. By your standards every noob is a cargo cult programmer.

Comment: Also I won't edit the question to make me look less stupid/ignorant. People usually learn from mistakes not only from smart questions and examples of challenging engineering problems.

Comment: @Byakkun: What's wrong with the title is that it doesn't describe the question. It just consists of two words describing a language feature, and thus is completely useless in a list of questions. And `By your standards every noob is a cargo cult programmer` is just flat-out wrong, but nice strawman.

Comment: @DejanLekic: Nobody's stopping you from answering. However you ought to respect the concept that everybody is free to vote as they see fit, including you!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Whoever does not like the question for whatever reasons should simply leave the thread if the quality is not up to his or her standard, instead of downvoting and discouraging people.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I fail to see the context I've took your sarcasm out of, but however I've edited the title even tough I don't think it changes the fact that I've formulated a wrong question to begin with. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Byakkun: I was not being sarcastic.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: sorry then. May have misunderstood. Let's just end this conversation - it leads to nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example with `foo()` that does exactly what you asked in the OP, plus the `foovar()` function which can take arbitrary number of parameters. In this case I accept only string arguments, but you may change the code to accept anything.

```
import std.stdio;
import core.vararg;

string foo (string nonopt, string opt = "") {
  string ret;
  if (opt.length == 0)
    ret = nonopt;
  else
    ret = nonopt ~ ";" ~ opt;

  return ret;
} // foo() function

string foovar(string nonopt, ...) {
  string ret = nonopt ~ "/";
  for (int i = 0; i < _arguments.length; i++) {
    // we want to use only string arguments to build the result
    if (_arguments[i] == typeid(string)) {
      ret ~= va_arg!(string)(_argptr) ~ "/";
    } // if
  } // for
  return ret;
} // foovar() function

int main() {
  string a = "x@a.t", b = "a.t";
  auto s = foo(a);
  auto s2 = foo(a, b);
  auto s3 = foovar(a, "D", "rules");
  writeln(s);   // x@a.t
  writeln(s2);  // x@a.t;a.t
  writeln(s3);  // x@a.t/D/rules/
  return 0;
} //  main() function
```

Comment: The most insightful answer. I ended using variadic function after all because I added some more functionality to my program thanks to your example, even thought I now realize my initial question did not require it.

Comment: Also consider the example by Jonathan which uses variadic template feature. It is a good way of dealing with varargs.

Answer (score 7):

What you're asking for doesn't sound variadic at all. You know exactly how many arguments there are supposed to be - either 1 or 2. In that case, just use a default argument for the second parameter. e.g.

```
void func(string required, string optional = null) {}
```

If what you want is a `string` followed by an unknown number of strings, then you'd probably want to do something like

```
void func(string required, string[] optional...)
```

If, on the other hand, what you want is something which takes a `string` followed by an unknown number of arguments of a variety of types, then what you want is a [variadic template](http://www.d-programming-language.org/variadic-function-templates.html).

```
void func(T...)(string required, T optional) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you wan't something like:

```
void foo(string required, string optional = "") {}
```

Or maybe like (not tested):

```
class Optional(T) {
  private T _val;
  public this(in T val) { _val = val; }
  @property public T get() { return _val; }
}

void foo(string required, Optional!(string) = null) {}
```

Comment: No, but the second idea is interesting but overkill for what I want considering that what I want is in the language specification http://dlang.org/function.html#variadic. Also see my edit. Sorry for being too vague.

Comment: The first implementation of foo() is **exactly** what you described in your OP.

Comment: Sorry @Hauleth. You were right. I was just so convinced that I have to use variadic functions to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a C-style variadic function, in which case check out [core.vararg](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/core_vararg.html). The preferred D solution is to use a templated function:

```
import std.stdio;

void foo(Args...)(string first, Args args)
{
    writeln("First argument is ", first);
    foreach (i, A; Args)
    {
        writefln("Type of %s argument is %s, value is %s",
                    i, A.stringof, args[i]);
    }
}

void main(){
    foo("bar", 1, 4.0, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would the following not do?

```
void myFunction(string nonOptionalParameter, string optionalParameter="default value")
{
  // Your code here
}
```

Comment: @Byakkun this is exactly what you asked for (`string foo(string nonopt,string opt=""){...}` can be called with `foo(a)` or `foo(a,b)` like in you code snippet with the `opt` parameter defaulting to the empty string when not supplied)